# How can I view the raw XML of an RSS feed in Safari (or Reeder)?

Tags: safari, podcasts, rss, xml, google

I want to see the raw XML of an RSS feed for a podcast.

In Safari, as of Lion formatted XML files is supported. But RSS feeds are not formatted that way and instead presented in Safari's RSS Reader mode. A view source on that page doesn't display the RSS feed as I expected, instead the HTML and CSS used to put the viewer together.

Is there another way to do this in Safari? I also have the RSS Reading app, Reeder, installed, so I'd be willing to do it in there if possible.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here’s a Safari extension to view the raw XML data: https://github.com/sergeche/xmlview#readme

[image]

There’s an online demo, too: http://media.chikuyonok.ru/xmlview/ This works in Firefox, Chrome, and Safari.

**Edit:** Sadly, this extension doesn’t work in Safari 5.1. There’s an issue for that here: https://github.com/sergeche/xmlview/issues/16

---

Alternatively, you could always open Terminal.app and just use `curl` to view the raw RSS/XML contents:

```
curl "http://example.org/some-feed.rss"
```

Comment: Doesn't seem to work for RSS feeds.

Comment: Doesn't seem to work for plain XML either.

Comment: The curl above solution works best if you just want to see what the site is sending you. It is raw, and meant to be. You do not need the quotes on the url if it is properly formed and has no spaces.

Comment: @GaryHam “You do not need the quotes on the url if it is properly formed and has no spaces.” Yes you do — for example, if it contains an ampersand (`&`) symbol. It’s easiest to just always use the quotes.