# Formatted XML display in Safari 8

Tags: safari, safari-extensions, xml

I'm trying to find an extension or plugin that allows Safari to display XML in a more user friendly form, similar to how its handled by Firefox.

The only relevant information seems to be heavily outdated and not applicable to the latest version (8.0.7).

[How can I view the raw XML of an RSS feed in Safari (or Reeder)?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/46038/how-can-i-view-the-raw-xml-of-an-rss-feed-in-safari-or-reeder) had an answer about 'XV XML Viewer', but the answer itself has been updated pointing out that it no longer works in Safari 5.1.

There is also an older .webplugin that could have been used, but then I read that the .webplugin mechanism itself is deprecated and no longer used in modern versions.

Is there any updated extension that can show a formatted xml view in current Safari versions? The ability to collapse/expand nodes would be nice, but atleast basic formatting would still be better than just a giant blob of text whenever I view a web service from Safari instead of Firefox.

Answer (score 1):

You do not need an extension or plugin. What you should do is supply an appropriate XSL. The browser will use this to format the XML for display. See http://www.w3schools.com/xsl/default.asp for more information.